# I don't know why 'IndexError: list index out of range' came out

Tags: python, indexing

[image: Code]

I don't know where I made mistake in the range of list index..
I want to compare the component on the same index between two lists.

For example :

```
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X']
```

then (what i hope..)come out:

```
4period:O
```

I want you to explain with the basic code.. plz help :(

> IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Please post the actual code and not an image of it!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to:
clarify title of question, more details or clarify of problem, improve content quality, improve text arragement, improve code formatting, include [example] of your code, include the current result, include the expected result.
See [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You have defined c as a dictionary but used it as a  list later to append into it. Error it occurring because of it.